# Django.server logging configuration not working in Django Daphne

Tags: python, django, daphne

I wanted to increase logging level in order to decrease spam in logs with all 2XX responses. According to Django docs and other SO questions I have changed level of `django.server` logger to `WARNING` in `settings.py`. Unfortunately, this change does not work when I run my server using daphne. To verify, I ran my app using `manage.py runserver` and there the config was working.

I've also tried changing log level (using `LOGGING = {}` in `settings.py`) of all loggers in `logging.root.manager.loggerDict`, also unsuccessfully.

Anyone has some idea on how to either determine which logger logs the messages like presented below in daphne or how to force daphne to respect `django.server` log assuming it works as I expect?

Sample log message I'm talking about:

```
127.0.0.1:33724 - - [21/Apr/2021:21:45:13] "GET /api/foo/bar" 200 455
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer myself. In case someone has same problem:

After diving into Daphne source code it looks like as of now it does not use standard `logging` library, but relies on own class that writes all access log messages to `stdout` or given file. I do not see a possibility of increasing the log level.

Consult https://github.com/django/daphne/blob/main/daphne/access.py for more details.

Comment: Did you try setting the log level with the `basicConfig`? Like: `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s')`

Comment: I did, but the file I mentioned in my answer does not seem to take any sort of log level into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

set verbosity to 0 and you are done

```
daphne -v 0 xxx.asgi:application
```